# Deploying war file using ant task in MobileFirst

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm trying to deploy a war file using ant task in MobileFirst WAS Liberty server.

I'm following this tutorial:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/t_ant_tasks_configure_appserver.html

When I enter this command:
"ant -f configure-liberty-oracle.xml install"

I'm receiving this error message in the cmd:

> BUILD FAILED
>   C:\IBM\MobileFirst_Platform_Server\shortcuts\configure-liberty-oracle.xml:69: C:
>   \IBM\MobileFirst_Platform_Server\shortcuts****UPDATE**** - MobileFirst Server installation directory (example: \opt\IBM\MobileFirst_Platform_Server)\WorklightServer does not exist.

When I opened the "configure-liberty-oracle.xml" I can see the line "(example: \opt\IBM\MobileFirst_Platform_Server)" but I don't know what to do.

Sorry I'm new to ant so I'm not also sure if I'm on the right path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the sample ant scripts, it is required that they are first updated to match the specifics of your environment.  Everywhere that "****UPDATE****" appears, the entire text in the quotes should be replaced with a value that is appropriate for your environment.  So in this case, the value for "worklight.server.install.dir" should be updated to reflect your installation directory for MobileFirst.  From the output that you provided, the value would be "C:\IBM\MobileFirst_Platform_Server".  There are a number of other properties that need to be modified as well.  I would suggest that you make a copy of the file to be customized, and to keep the original sample file as-is.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Tom, I can see the build successful now in cmd but I can't see the war file in the Server Configuration Tool?

Comment: Glad to hear that helped.  The configurations that are shown in the Server Configuration Tool are those that are created through the tool, and you cannot use the tool to add runtimes to a configuration that was created or updated using Ant.  See the limitations listed on the following page:  http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.0.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_using_server_config_tool.html?lang=en